# How to reuse existing user/group data in Activiti?

Tags: integration, activiti

I have a webapp which has user/group functions, and existing user/group data.

I want to use Activiti the process engine, however, it seems Activiti manage user/group info itself.

Should I:

1. Refactor my existing webapp, to reuse the user/group data from Activiti, or
2. Write some adapter code, to make Activiti reuse user/group data in my existing database? Maybe, another implmentation of `RepositoryService`, `IdentityService`, etc., and recompile? It seems `RepositionServiceImpl` is hard coded in the Activiti sources, and there isn't a `setRepositionService()` method in `ProcessEngine`.

I can't rename the existing db tables, because there are some other apps using them.

I have read the user guide, but I didn't found any information on how to integrate Activiti with existing apps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know what version you are currently using, but I used your second option successfully with version 5.5, overriding some Activiti classes:

1. Extend `GroupManager` and `UserManager` (from package `org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity`), and implement the methods you need, using the required DAOs/EntityManager/whatever pointing to your database. Code here: [GroupManager](http://pastebin.com/KCV3R0dg) / [UserManager](http://pastebin.com/EK8t4sQG).
2. Implement `org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.SessionFactory.SessionFactory`, for groups and users. Check out code here: [ActivitiGroupManagerFactory](http://pastebin.com/6k0fEAi4) / [ActivitiUserManagerFactory](http://pastebin.com/ipfR1CtQ).
3. Finally, in your activity config you have to set your new SessionFactory classes. I was using spring, so there is my activiti-config bean code: [activiti-config.xml](http://pastebin.com/zPwYUfBK) (check line 14)

Hope this helps in some way :)

Comment: can you please share these codes and config file to my mailbox, i can't open your link at all. always show "stolen content from pastebin.com. your request has been blocked! visit pastebin.com for the original content.", my email: sendreams@hotmail.com, thanks

Comment: i use a ec2 vpn, and now pastebin is ok.

Comment: tip:i used version 5.17, the GroupManager's name has changed to "GroupEntityManager", UserManager -> "UserEntityManager"

Answer (score 2):

You can check the Lim Chee Kin code to integrate activiti with spring security https://github.com/limcheekin/activiti-spring-security and maybe you can reuse your user/group data with spring security this way you can reuse his code.